# JavaScript Open/Display current page in new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Is it possible to open a page in a new window or tab from within the page?

Yes, I mean **current** HTML page itself. Not by the call from another one like this:

```
window.open('page.html','_blank');
```

Could be JS and `<body onLoad=...>` manipulations.

Need this for modifying quite complex CGI, where only few actions supposed to open in a new window. 
Cannot modify the code, so only pure HTML+JS solution needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just pass current address to window.open():

```
window.open(window.location.href, '_blank');
```

[**Code example**](https://gist.github.com/3371881)

Comment: without if(!window.opener), your page will open in a new window recursively, isn't ??

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!window.opener){
    window.open(window.location.href,'_blank'); 
}
```